# Search and Replace with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to search through text for a specific word and then add a html tag around that word.For example if i had the string "I went to the shop to buy apples and oranges" and wanted to add html bold tags around apples.

The problem, the word i search the string with is stored in a text file and can be uppercase,lowercase etc.When i use preg_replace to do this i manage to replace it correctly adding the tags but for example if i searched for APPLES and the string contained "apples" it would change the formatting from apples to APPLES, i want the format to stay the same.

I have tried using preg_replace but i cant find a way to keep the same word casing.This is what i have:

```
foreach($keywords as $value)
    {
        $pattern = "/\b$value\b/i";
        $replacement = "<b>$value</b>";
        $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    }
```

So again if $value was APPLES it would change every case format of apples in the $string to uppercase due to $replacemant having $value in it which is "APPLES".

How could i achieve this with the case format staying the same and without having to do multiple loops with different versions of case format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `$value` verbatim in the replacement, you can use the literal strings `\0` or `$0`.  Just as `\n`/`$n`, for some integer `n`, refers back to the `n`th capturing group of parentheses, `\0`/`$0` is expanded to the entire match.  Thus, you'd have

```
foreach ($keywords as $value) {
  $new_string = preg_replace("/\\b$value\\b/i", '<b>$0</b>', $string);
}
```

Note that `'<b>$0</b>'` uses single quotes.  You *can* get away with double quotes here, because `$0` isn't interpreted as a reference to a variable, but I think this is clearer.  In general, you have to be careful with using a `$` inside a double-quoted string, as you'll often get a reference to an existing variable unless you escape the `$` as `\$`.  Similarly, you should escape the backslash in `\b` inside the double quotes for the pattern; although it doesn't matter in this specific case, in general backslash is a meaningful character within double quotes.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but if what you are struggling on is differentiating between upper-case letter (APPLE) and lower-case letter (apple), then the first thing you could do is convert the word into upper-case, or lower-case, and then run the tests to find it and put HTML tags around it. That is just my guess and maybe I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: In the string apples could be set as APPLES,aPPles,APPels etc and i wanted to search the word apples no matter its format, then replace keeping its same format in the string from where it was replaced. I could of had multiple instances of apples in different formats and searched exactly but this could led to many loops to change only one word.

Answer (score 0):

In the code exists offtopic error: the result value have been rewritten on not first loop iteration. And ending value of `$new_string` will be only last replacement.

Comment: correct, misleading as it is this was only partial code that i used for testing and looped only once. Really it should be $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); in its current format